# getting a CastError, ObjectId failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a route that is inserting an array of documents into a collection. I also want to capture the _is of the document into a user schema but I'm getting a CastError, how do I resolve this. here is my code:

the error:

```
(node:23088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "
  {
    _id: 6032c1df6761405a308736f0,
    name: ' test1',
    surname: 'test',
    email: 'example@example.com',
    phone: '0915461',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 6032c1df6761405a308736f1,
    name: 'jane',
    surname: 'doe',
    email: 'jane@gmail.com',
    phone: '12345678',
    __v: 0
  }
]" at path "references"
```

route:

```
app.post('/register_two/:id/references', async (req, res) => {
    const staff = await Worker.findById(req.params.id);
    
    const reference = await Reference.insertMany(req.body.references);
    
    await staff.references.push(reference); <<--- Error when i try to push document IDs

    
});
```

my reference schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ReferenceSchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    email: String,
    phone: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reference', ReferenceSchema);
```

my worker schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const WorkerSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    role: String,
    nationality: String,
    gender: String,
    dateofbirth: Date,
    contactnumber: String,
    email: String,
    address: String,
    region: String,
    righttowork: String,
    righttoworkproof: String,
    ninumber: String,
    references: [
        {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Reference'
        }
    ],
    date: Date
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Worker', WorkerSchema);
```

edit: fixed worker schema

Comment: Your Worker schema is the same as your reference schema?

Comment: @codemonkey thanks for that, had made a mistake, i corrected it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it using the spread operator, all I did was change:

```
await staff.references.push(reference);
```

to

```
await staff.references.push(...reference);
```

Comment: Hmmm. Good to know. Thank you for posting.

Answer (score 1):

You should run the `insertMany` command with the `rawResult` option set to true

```
const reference = await Reference.insertMany(req.body.references, {rawResult: true});
```

This way you will get the raw result from the MongoDB driver back into `reference`. That result will be an object that will contain this prop:

```
...
...
insertedIds: { '0': 6032ce0ed7fd8568aef0d0cd, '1': 6032ce0ed7fd8568aef0d0ce, ... }
...
```

`insertedIds` is what you need, but you need them in the form of an array. So here is what your code should look like:

```
const reference = await Reference.insertMany(req.body.references, {rawResult: true});
await staff.references.push(...Object.values(reference.insertedIds));
```

Credit to Emil C., who pointed out that by pushing an array we would simply be creating array of arrays inside the `reference` path. Spreading is the answer.

Comment: Hi, when I try this, it returns undefined for reference.insertedIds or reference.id but in my collections the 2 references will have been added with their Ids. when I log reference I get the same array of objects as I posted in the error message.

Comment: @EmilC. My fault. I completely neglected the fact that you're using mongoose. Give me one sec, I will correct the answer.

Comment: @EmilC. Updated. Tested this on my end. Works fine.

Comment: i still got an error: (node:25544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[ 6032d20ab4072663c8212114,
 6032d20ab4072663c8212115 ]" at path "references". i managed to solve it though with the spread operator, thank you very much